# Untitled (Not Just a) Word Search

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, word-search

I wrote this for a puzzle swap, and I'm somewhat proud of how it turned out.  I'd like to know what you think.

```
T I U C R I C Z T A S R E J H U
T N A L L A G A I J U N K E T U
T E M N O I P M A H C N F G I P
Z K Q N O I T A N I R G E R E P
C U T O F F F F O R G E D Q E D
V E P M N P G N I T U O M O Z O
E S S F A L S E T H C A T E D N
T R E D H E R R I N G T M X O F
A E U X I M N U D N U O R I L E
L V D Y Z X P T E I Q Z S P U G
U A O X S A R S P D S R T Z X A
S R Q U L A I J X P U J Z Q A Y
N T G A V U Q M E C H M O H T O
I O D E R O V Z X O Q O M I E V
B I L C Z Y R E V E S Z N Y N H
N C A V A L I E R C Y G N Y N N
```

I've tried to minimize their existence, but words shorter than 5 letters are spurious.

The solution is a short phrase, you'll know it when you get it.  Yes, there is more to this puzzle than the simple word search.

Hint:

> All words fall into a small number of distinct categories.

Meta:

> I want to add more tags but they are spoilery.  I don't really know what I normally accepted on this site.  Guidance?

Hint policy:
I will be adding hints once every day.

Daily Hint #1:

> Good job on solving the word search.  The categories are your clues to proceed further, but you may have already guessed that.  So I will say that two of the clues tell you what to do.  One clue tells you how do to it.  And the final clue tells you what to use it on.

Daily Hint #2:

> I checked Wikipedia, and it looks like there are 18 quadrillion different Knight tours possible on an 8x8 board. So even if there was some hint telling you where to start (X marks the spot was clever, and I wish I had thought of that), I'd have to also specify where you go next approx 54 more times. Clearly, I'm not doing that, so how can I tell you which tour to use only using one of the hints?

Daily Hint #2.5 (Bonus):

> The relevant hint is the group meaning "separated" or "disconnected."  How can a knight's tour be separated from itself?

Daily Hint #3:

> The actual root words for each of the four groups are "knight", "fake", "tour", and "uncrossed"

Comment: Guidance on tags, if you want people to figure out what type of puzzle this is, I suggest the [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] tag

Comment: Just to clarify, are 5 letter words allowed? And also are diagonals allowed? And one final thing, can a letter be part of multiple words?

Comment: I believe the answers are yes, yes, and yes. (But I haven't solved the puzzle and my guesses are therefore only guesses.)

Comment: The answers are indeed yes, yes, and yes.

Comment: I find that rot13(zbfg bs gur jbeqf snyy vagb tebhcf, nf lbh fnl, ohg gurer vf bar gung nethnoyl tbrf jvgu bar tebhc ohg vf _nffbpvngrq_ jvgu n eryrinag jbeq engure guna orvat n _ebhtu flabalz_ yvxr nyy gur bguref, naq bar gung frrzf abg gb svg nalguvat ryfr. Gur ynggre, arne gur obggbz yrsg, vf bevtvanyyl n Yngva jbeq. Jbhyq lbh pner gb pbzzrag ba rvgure? R.t., vf gur frpbaq bs gubfr jbeqf, na nppvqrag? vf gur svefg, arne gur prager, zrnag gb or cneg bs gur tebhc vg'f "nffbpvngrq jvgu"?)

Comment: (My apologies if my comment above is too cryptic even after un-ROT13-ing; I want to avoid giving away more than necessary to anyone who is curious enough to read but doesn't want to know what words I found.)

Comment: Don't read this comment if you don't want to know the found words:
are the two words in question rot13(vafhyngr naq ebhaq)?

Comment: The first of those is not either of mine. The second is my first one. My second one is rot13(PERQB).

Comment: (The first one you mention seems to me to rot13(svg irel pbzsbegnoyl vagb bar bs gur tebhcf).)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan rot13(PERQB) is spurious, and that is somewhat unfortunate, if you give me a moment, I can edit the puzzle and remove it.  I did not notice it.  As for your other one, it is intended and part of one of the groups.

Comment: Ok, that has been rectified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The final phrase:

> The black knight always triumphs!

Which is

> A quote from Monty Python's Holy Grail

---

#### The Completed Word Search:

> [image]

All the words in the word search:

> **Forward words:**
>
> Cutoff, Forged, False, Red herring, Cavalier, Junket
>
> **Down/Up words:**
>
> Pseudo, expedition, insulate, traverse, voyage, luxate <sub>(Credit Lanny Strack)</sub>
>
> **Back words:**
>
> Circuit, gallant, champion, peregrination, detach, round, sever, ersatz, unmix, outing
>  <sub>(credit Gareth for the last three, would never have even known that 'ersatz' was a word lol)</sub>
>
> **Diagonal words:**
>
> Excursion, bogus, paladin, travel, cruise, phony, dummy, disjoin <sub>(Credit Jens)</sub>

These words can be put under 4 distinct groups:

> **Tour**:
>
> Expedition, traverse, circuit, excursion, travel, cruise, junket, voyage, outing, peregrination <sub>(credit Zimonze)</sub>
>
> **Fake**:
>
> Forged, false, red herring, bogus, phony, dummy, pseudo, ersatz
>
> **'Uncrossed'**:
>
> Cutoff, sever, detach, insulate, unmix, disjoin, luxate
>
> **Knight** (spotted by Rand and Gareth):
>
> Cavalier, gallant, paladin, champion
>
> Also notice that 'round' can fit in both the knight and tour groups, which shows a connection.

So now what?

> These categories are actually instructions: **Knight Tour, Fake, Uncrossed**:
>
> What do we have to do? A **knight's tour**
> How do we do it? **Fake**
> What do we use it on? **Uncrossed**
>
> i.e. - an 'uncrossed' knight's tour after removing the fake letters,

So:

> If we remove all the letters in the wordsearch which are part of a word (i.e. 'fake') we get left with exactly 64 letters, which just so happens to be the number of squares on a chessboard. So these letters can be re-arranged into a 8x8 grid:
>
> ```
> J H U A I U T E
>
> M N F G I P Z K
>
> Q F Q E D V M N
>
> P M O Z O T M X
>
> F Y Z X Q Z P X
>
> T Z Q J Z Q Q M
>
> H O V Z O Q Z Y
>
> Z H C Y G N N N
> ```

So the next thing is to do

> An 'uncrossed' knights tour. The 'uncrossed' tour leads us to the longest uncrossed tour on an 8x8 grid, via wikipedia:
>
>  [image]
>
> Applying this, and starting at the left hand starting point gives 'ONETIMEPADFJFFQMXQOPVXQNQJGVZZZZZZZZ'.
>
> And a one-time pad is a [type of vigenere cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)

So what next? (Huge credit to Lanny Strack here, who managed to work this out)

> Using all the letters in the 8x8 grid that the knight doesn't pass over as the cipher-text:
>
>  `HUIUTMGZKQNPMYQXTQMHOOYHCYNN`
>
> And then removing the Zs at the end of the knights tour string so the key is
>
>  `ONETIMEPADFJFFQMXQOPVXQNQJGV`
>
> Using a one time pad cipher we get the answer:
>
> '**THE BLACK KNIGHT ALWAYS TRIUMPHS**'

Comment: You forgot two P-words in your "fake" group list.

Comment: Another group might be associated with "knight" (cavalier, gallant, paladin, peregrin, champion).

Comment: I think of the groups as rot13(XAVTUG:4, GEVC:11, FCYVG:6 naq SNXR:7).

Comment: @Randal'Thor ahh good thinking! Also thanks I have no idea how I managed to make a list and miss out half the things that should be there lol

Comment: @Gareth That doesn't look very rot13'ed, Tnergu.

Comment: BG is missing at least the following: rot13(REFNGM, BHGVAT). I fixed the not-rot-ing.

Comment: Oh, and rot13(HAZVK). EDITED to add: And rot13(QVFWBVA).

Comment: Back when rot13(PERQB) was in the grid and it hadn't been confirmed that rot13(EBHAQ) belongs with another group, presumably the rot13(GEVC) group, I had a halfbaked theory that rot13(PERQB uvagrq ng OVFUBC) and of course rot13(gurer jnf n XAVTUG tebhc), and rot13(SNXR fhttrfgrq PURNG juvpu fhttrfgrq EBBX). But I couldn't get the other three to work out at all :-).

Comment: I also remark, almost certainly futilely, on the rot13(eulzrf XAVTUG/SYVTUG naq OERNX/SNXR). But I think rot13(GEVC vf fb irel zhpu orggre guna SYVTUG gung guvf vf ubcryrff rira vs V pbhyq guvax bs n tbbq jnl gb hfr vg).

Comment: There are rot13(pbafcvphbhfyl srj vagrefrpgvbaf, fhttrfgvat gung jr ybbx ng rot13(gur vagrefrpgvba yrggref. V trg ABVEQRHR juvpu qbrfa'g frrz yvxr vg'f na nantenz bs nalguvat vagrerfgvat, nynf).

Comment: Anyway, I need to go to bed. (More precisely, I needed to go to bed an hour or two ago.) I'm sure this'll have been solved by the time I next look...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan same tbh, puzzling gets you hooked lmao, thanks for the help!! I’ll give this a bit longer but otherwise sleep beats us all in the end, we’ll probably see what everyone else comes up with :P

Comment: rot13(V guvax crerteva naq angvba ner npghnyyl crertevangvba, n jbeq gung svgf va gur "geniry" tebhc.) this makes the categories nicer.

Comment: @Zimonze ahhhh that’s makes a LOT more sense, thanks!!

Comment: You mentioned being afraid that some of the words you found were unintended. rot13(Nyy jbeqf gung lbh unir sbhaq fb sne ner vagraqrq. Ohg lbh unir abg lrg sbhaq gurz nyy.)

Comment: There's also rot13(Qvfwbva (znva qvntbany) naq Ynune (qvntbany fgnegvat nobhg unysjnl hc gur svefg pbyhza). Gur Ynune qbrfa'g frrz gb svg nal tebhc fb znl or n syhxr)

Comment: Today I learned about the word rot13(Ynune). I'll edit the puzzle tomorrow morning to eliminate the false positive.

Comment: Still haven't figured out the short phrase, but another word in the puzzle is rot13(yhkngr). If you look up the definition, it is obvious which of the categories it goes into.

Comment: Ha. I just looked at the diagram showing what letters BG had crossed off and didn't notice he had rot13(CRERTEVA naq ANGVBA jurer V unq CRERTEVANGVBA)! I agree with Zimonze about that. I hadn't seen rot13(YHKNGR) which is a nice find.

Comment: @LannyStrack I’ve been staring at that area for ages wondering if there’s a word there, turns out I just didn’t know the word lol

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity hmmm I’m assuming there can’t be that many left now... and also for ‘lahar’ (I won’t bother with rot13 because it’s unintended and soon to be removed) I think you can just change the H to something else, unless the H is needed in which case just put a disclaimer :)

Comment: Your group list is missing rot13(WHAXRG) although it's highlighted in your grid. I was thinking of rot13(EBHAQ) as going in the rot13(GEVC) group because of rot13("ebhaq gevc") but your classification could be right too.

Comment: Another two things worth mentioning. 1. rot13(Gur frg bs yrggref hfrq sbe gur jbeqfrnepu vf fhfcvpvbhfyl pybfr gb orvat flzzrgevpny yrsg-gb-evtug; pna fbzrguvat pyrire or qbar jvgu gur zvfzngpurf?) 2. rot13(Gurer ner n srj cynprf jurer gurer ner fhfcvpvbhf arne-ercrgvgvbaf orgjrra gjb pbafrphgvir ebjf; ybbx ng ABV arne gbc yrsg naq ALA arne obggbz evtug. Whfg pbvapvqrapr?)

Comment: Good morning.  With rot13(qvfwbva) and rot13(yhkngr) I think that rot13(lbh'ir sbhaq nyy bs gur jbeqf va gur jbeq frnepu frpgvba bs guvf chmmyr. Pbatenghyngvbaf, abj gur erny chmmyr ortvaf.)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity nows for the really tricky bet then :P

Comment: The first hint makes me wonder about a rot13(XAVTUG'F GBHE) but then I'm having trouble seeing rot13(ubj gur bgure gjb tebhcf ner nccyvrq).

Comment: A minor comment, in your word search image, for rot13(PHGBSS lbh unir PHGBSSS uvtuyvtugrq.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'm also wondering whether rot13(Gur sbhe tebhcf pna or fcyvg vagb gjb tebhcf bs gjb, fhpu nf SVK SNXR, ZBIR XAVTUG be fbzrguvat nybat gubfr yvarf naq gurl ner npghnyyl vafgehpgvbaf) but I'm not sure how that would work

Comment: Have you seen the hint OE added to the question? It says rot13("gjb bs gur pyhrf gryy lbh jung gb qb; bar pyhr gryyf lbh ubj gb qb vg; gur svany pyhr gryyf lbh jung gb hfr vg ba") and that the "clues" are the four categories, which I've been calling (perhaps suboptimally) rot13(XAVTUG, GEVC, FCYVG naq SNXR). It seems plausible enough that rot13(XAVTUG naq GEVC=>GBHE ner gryyvat hf gb znxr n xavtug'f gbhe) but then I don't see how to make appropriate use of the other groups.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I think I've just seen a super important breakthrough, let me add to my answer and tell me what you think...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I feel like I know what you're talking about. I copied your grid, but the mistake pointed out in OE's comment was important, right...? (I might be super dumb though) rot13(gurer ner fvkgl sbhe hahfrq fdhnerf)

Comment: @Zimonze yep see my edit, that mistake turned out crucial

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan after adding in that update, I'm almost certain you're right. I just dont know where the piece should start

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity is this next step correct?

Comment: You are correct; however, rot13(ybh unir gur zrnavat bs bar bs gur pngrtbevrf irel fyvtugyl jebat.)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I'm assuming that the rot13(snxr) group isn't quite right. I've edited slightly

Comment: rot13(Snxr vf npghnyyl gur rknpg anzr V unq sbe gur pngrtbel.  Gur ceboyrzngvp bar vf erzbir.  Gur jbeqf va gung pngrtbel svg orggre jvgu n fyvtugyl qvssrerag jbeq.)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity hmm ok, I'll try and find a synonym that makes sense here

Comment: Think of it this way, if I was rot13(hfvat erzbir, V pbhyq unir hfrq rnfvre jbeqf, yvxr qvfpneq be ryvzvangr.  V jbhyqa'g unir unq gb qvt qbja sbe fhcre grpuavpny jbeqf yvxr yhkngr, be engure bqq sbezf yvxr qvfwbva).

Comment: I feel like the correct word is probably rot13(Frcnengr) but might also be rot13(vfbyngr) - I have no idea how this would tell us where to begin the... journey.. however (@OmnipotentEntity)

Comment: That's much closer.  And that clue is the one that will give you the answer you seek.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity hmmm... my only idea was to look for a letter that was ‘alone’ i.e. there was only one of it but there are four such letters. I must admit I’m stuck, perhaps Gareth will have some insight into it from here

Comment: I'll let this simmer, and if you guys haven't made progress it will be tomorrow's hint.  Good progress so far.

Comment: The thing I keep coming back to is rot13(Sbhe "hahfrq" yrggref va gur tevq jrer punatrq ol gur BC jvgu rqvgf gb gur chmmyr. Fb vg frrzf gb zr gung znlor jr arrq gb hfr fbzrguvat bgure guna gur hahfrq yrggref.) I can't get anything to work so far, though, even using hint #2. I've tried lots of permutations already.

Comment: @Lanny Strack The current approach is on the right track. There's only one more insight that's required to move to the next stage.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - That saves me a lot of time. Thanks.

Comment: @everybody - If any of you solvers would like me to share which KT I am using, I am happy to do that. However, I think all of you can figure that out on your own with the hint given, so I'll refrain for now.

Comment: And, by the way, I have not achieved any notable results after using that KT. I am still trying lots of techniques to massage the results of it into something usable, with no success so far.

Comment: @LannyStrack Can you describe what you found with your KT? I can let you know if you have the correct one.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - If I apply my KT to the 8x8 letter grid posted by BG at the end of the above answer, the first three letters generated are XTE.

Comment: Based on Hint 2.5, I am probably operating with an incorrect assumption, because I was assuming that rot13(gur 'frcnengr' xrljbeq gbyq ubj gb "frcnengr" gur hahfrq jbeq frnepu yrggref naq cynpr gurz vagb n arj 8k8 tevq.).

Comment: If you have the correct KT you'll know it, as you start generating English text

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity daily hint? _bats eylids_

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - My assumption is that OE, noticing no apparent activity in the comments or answers, simply treated Hint 2.5 (the SECOND hint from yesterday!) as today's hint.

Comment: I just hadn't woken up yet today.

Comment: Or that.          ........

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity solved, nice puzzle!!! The only thing I'd say is we would never had got 'uncrossed' from those words as that's very obscure, but everything else worked very nicely!!

Comment: Unfortunately, uncrossed doesn't have many close and direct synonyms to pull from. :(  If you have any ideas for improving the conveyance I would be open to suggestions. I considered trying to fit it as a word search in the 8x8 grid, but it's a long word, and there are too many cross dependencies for it to work at any location I searched.

Comment: One time pad isn't the answer though.  There's still more, keep going.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I'm assuming from here that the left over letters are the ciphertext of a one time pad. However i have no idea what the key could be here, because for obvious reasons it must be at least 64 characters long, and the only thing here like that is the original wordsearch, but using that as a key gives gibberish... can I just confirm that the left over letters are the ciphertext and the key is (min) 64 characters?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity also this is an incredibly well thought out and layered puzzle!! It deserves a lot more credit here!! I don't know how you could have clued 'uncrossed' either however, it's a tricky word

Comment: Keep pulling letters on the KT and it may become obvious.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity ok I've now pulled all the letters, thought I had it when I saw there 26 additional characters and thought the alphabet must be the key but was wrong. I've added it in, I just need to work out the key

Comment: There sure are a lot of Zs at the end.  What could it mean?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity this is so frustrating lmao I'm so close. I'll keep trying random keys, I've already tried Zs, backwards alphabet etc, so far only gibberish

Comment: There are 8 Z's. The title is "Untitled", which also has 8 characters. Perhaps the Z's correspond to spaces or similar.

Comment: All of the letters in the entire grid are used for something at least once.  As sort of an unintended meta hint, when I had to change the grid to fix spurious words, what did I have to change?  Why did I have to do that?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil you're very close, but I think you may have been bitten by an assumption.  There are 64 letters remaining.  36 are used in the knight's tour.  10 letters are in ONETIMEPAD, and 8 are in ZZZZZZZZ.  Knowing that I've used all of the letters for something at least once, which length fits?

Comment: I've got the answer, but I won't post it. That would be rude.

Comment: @LannyStrack honeslty, I'm completely stumped. Please do post!! I'll probably edit it in to my answer so it's fully complete crediting you, but you deserve the credit for solving! I'm completely stuck and I've been trying everything

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I'm probably gonna kick myself here, but I've been trying everything I can think of. Think you've stumped me at the final hurdle here :P If Lanny posts the answer I'll edit it in and credit him so its a complete answer

Comment: I'll tell you how to do it, but I won't post. rot13(Gur M'f ner whfg cnqqvat naq ner hahfrq. Abg pbhagvat gurz, gurer ner 28 bgure yrggref chyyrq sebz gur XG. Vs lbh pbzcvyr nyy bs gur yrggref sebz gur 8k8 tevq abg hfrq va gur XG, lbh jvyy frr gung gurer ner 28 bs gubfr, gbb. Hfr gur "bargvzrcnq...." 28 nf gur xrl, naq gur XG hahfrq yrggref nf gur pvcuregrkg, naq qb n Ivtrarer.)

Comment: @LannyStrack oh wow, I had literally done that multiple times I just assumed 'one time pad' would also be removed. Well done!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Well done.  I await the edit so I can give you a hard earned check mark.  Congratulations on your triumph.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity wow! What an incredibly well layered puzzle! Was a joy to solve :)

Comment: I'm very glad you enjoyed it. :D

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity just realised there's now 75 comments here lmao whoops

Comment: "Please avoid extended discussions in the comments, take it to the chat" gave up after like 55 or so lol.

Comment: Also, I'm glad you picked out that round could fit in either category.  It was supposed to be a somewhat subtle hint that the two groups were connected.  (Making the rounds vs round table).

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - Now that it's all over, I'll explain my earlier confusion. rot13(V unq vagrecergrq gur gjb aba-XG xrl jbeqf nf [1]'qvivqr/frcnengr' naq [2]'snxr/ubnk'. V vagrecergrq [1] gb zrna 'qvivqr bhg gur hahfrq jbeq frnepu yrggref vagb gurve bja tevq'. Sbe [2], V fnj ba gur 'Xavtug'f gbhe' jvxvcrqvn cntr gung gurer jnf n snxr/ubnk purff-cynlvat znpuvar ohvyg va gur 18gu praghel pnyyrq "Gur Ghex", juvpu jnf pynvzrq gb or na nhgbzngba, ohg ernyyl unq n crefba uvqqra vafvqr. Bar bs gur gevpxf vg cresbezrq jnf n xavtug'f gbhe; gung XG cngu vf ba gung cntr. V gubhtug jr jrer gb hfr gung.)

Comment: oh dang, I didn't even think about that connection. :X  That's my bad.  Especially because it completely fits the clues.   Maybe a good way to fix that problem would be to use some of the squares on that path to spell out "ANOTHER" or "DIFFERENT" when it's possible?

Comment: And, by the way, great puzzle! As already mentioned by BG, though, the 'uncrossed' clue was too hard to figure out without being told.

Comment: Hey, I'm going to add some details in this [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106350/untitled-word-search-discussion).

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - I have provided some feedback / suggested changes. I placed it in the chat.